# Adding another sub query in existing subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to get the result as below from the same table date-wise records:

```
               Enrolled   Enrolled as Email  Enrolled as Text Deals Redeemed   
<First Date>   7          5                  2                6
<Next Date>    9          3                  6               14
```

Table structure look something like this:

```
Customer_id, field1, field2, responsecode, created_date
```

My current query is something like this:

```
select created_date,
   count(field1) Enrolled,
   count(case field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email,
   count(case field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell,
   count(responsecode) Deals_Redeemed
   from tblCustomer
   group by created_date
   order by created_date
```

Which works fine for the first three columns but for the four column that is "Deals redeemed" which is a sub query from another table.

```
Select COUNT(*) from tbl_TransactionDishout where DishoutResponseCode = '0000'
```

Table Structure is as below:
Table name is "tbl_TransactionDishout"

```
    [Trnx_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,    
    [OfferNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,   
    [MerchantID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    
    [TerminalID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    
    [DishoutResponseCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,    
    [Created] [datetime] NULL
```

Comment: What is the relation of between tblCustomer and tbl_TransactionDishout? Is it responsecode to DishoutResponseCode?

Comment: No relation between them..I only want the result to be displays in the date-wise order..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this. (The Deals_Redeemed value will be same for all rows, you said there is no relation between two tables)

```
select created_date,
    count(field1) Enrolled,
    count(case field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email,
    count(case field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell,
    (Select COUNT(*) from tbl_TransactionDishout where DishoutResponseCode = '0000') as Deals_Redeemed
from tblCustomer
    group by created_date
    order by created_date
```

Answer (score 0):

if your tbl_TransactionDishout has a joining ID column to your tblCustomer you should be able to do a separate query such as

```
select created_date,
count(field1) Enrolled,
count(case field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email,
count(case field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell,
cnt
from tblCustomer t, 
(select id, count(1) as cnt
from tbl_transactiondishout
group by id) tt
where t.id = tt.id
group by created_date
order by created_date
```

Comment: What is this id..?? There is no relation between those..

Comment: Then your next best thing is to join on the date and get the count of the transactiondishout by date and use the above concept to join on the date to your customer table...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
select 
    created_date,
    count(field1) Enrolled,
    count(case field1 when 'E-mail' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Email,
    count(case field1 when 'Cell Phone' then 1 end) Enrolled_as_Cell,
    (
        Select COUNT(*) 
        from tbl_TransactionDishout 
        where DishoutResponseCode = tblCustomer.responsecode
    ) as Deals_Redeemed
from 
    tblCustomer
group by 
    created_date
order by 
    created_date
```